# How to enable NodeJS Cassandra Tracing

Tags: node.js, cassandra

When tracing is ON on my Cassandra DB, is there a way I can retrieve the trace information through NodeJS API(s)?

Also when I enable Tracing ON on my Cassandra DB and perform an insert operation through the NodeJS application, I dont see any tracing logged in the system_traces tables. However if I perform insert/select operation in the cqlsh, i am able to see the tracing details. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Protocol level query tracing is not yet implemented in the Node.js driver for Cassandra, here is the [ticket for it](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-6).

Comment: thanks Jorge. Would you be able to help me on the second part of the question. Any ideas:
Also when I enable Tracing ON on my Cassandra DB and perform an insert operation through the NodeJS application, I dont see any tracing logged in the system_traces tables. However if I perform insert/select operation in the cqlsh, i am able to see the tracing details

Comment: Tracing ON is a cqlsh command only valid for cqlsh, it is not at Cassandra level but at query execution level. It does not affect connections made by other drivers.